Do I have the option of running cable for an electric dryer through either the attic or crawl space?
My dryer has its own 30 amp 240v circuit in the panel box, wired using a 10/2 Romex and 3-prong receptacle. I plan to replace the 10/2 Romex and 3-prong receptacle with 10/3 Romex and a 4-prong receptacle for better safety.
Currently, when coming out of the panel box, this 10/2 cable is bundled with all other cables (e.g. one other 10/2 for AC and several 12/2 and 12/3) in the attic and runs for about 8-10 meters before diverging. It then runs through a wall down to the crawlspace. It finally comes into the laundry room through the floor.
In the previous wiring, why did the cable for the dryer have to run through the crawl space but not directly from the attic like the separate cable for the washing machine?
I live in Illinois; I looked up the code. I didn't find any restrictions or specifics on this. If I run the new 10/3 cable along the 12/2 for the washer through the same path before connecting to the new 4-prong receptacle, would there be any problems or concerns?

If it is a single-floor house where the laundry room has the attic above and the crawl space below, I cannot imagine why it would be done this way.  Wild speculation: was the dryer somewhere else once?  Perhaps in the wall where the cable runs down ?  If so perhaps it was spliced there to move it where it is now?   I know I'm stretching for an answer. :)   (Or a cooker was in that wall and there was no dryer, then things got shuffled ..)

It is a single-floor house with both an attic above and a crawl space below. With the current setup, running the cable through the attic will definitely save 6-8 feet, and be easier. I can only think it was perhaps because of the remodelling the previous owner did 8 years ago.

There should be no problem taking the alternate path. One possibility for the existing setup is that the 12/2 for the washer was itself a newer installation than everything else and that there was no reason (there should have been a reason: safety) to redo the dryer circuit.
Make sure when you replace the 10-30 3-wire plug/cord on the dryer with a 14-30 4-wire plug/cord that you also remove the neutral/ground bond in the dryer. This is usually very easy to do. If you are not sure, post another question. You can also use a multimeter to easily test after you install the plug/cord to make sure neutral and ground are not connected.
An important note for future readers and/or other states:
According to this NFPA page, right now Illinois is nominally on the 2008 NEC but specifics may vary by county or city. (Notably, Chicago requires conduit, but presumably that is not the case in this question because there is already plenty of Romex in use.) As I understand it, except where local rules make exceptions, jurisdictions that have adopted the 2020 or 2023 versions of the NEC require GFCI protection on 240V plug/receptacle circuits such as dryers. While arguably a simple replacement of a 10-30 receptacle with a 14-30 should not trigger such a requirement, replacing the entire cable very likely does trigger that requirement.
Which all means: This answer is correct for non-Chicago parts of Illinois right now but next year it might not be and for 37 states, unless they have local exceptions to this particular rule, a GFCI breaker may be required as part of this circuit upgrade.

I'm aware of the code change for the GFCI requirement. Since I'm going to replace the entire cable, I do plan to replace the breaker, too.

@Vincent I'm saying that based on your description (Illinois, presumably not in Chicago) I think you are in a part of the USA where you do not need to spend an extra $100 (or more!) on a GFCI 30A double-breaker. You certainly can do that, but unless your local jurisdiction requires it, you don't need to. And you will add a lot of safety with the change to a 4-wire circuit.

Not in Chicago. Thanks for the remark! I've purchased the new breaker. But I will see how it goes; I can always return it. ;-D
